# Different Combobox values in different rows of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have DataGridView, in which, I would like to have two columns.

1. 1st column to show object name
2. 2nd column to show object value in combobox
3. In first row, I want to display information about "Birds" i.e. first column will have text  as "Birds" and second column will contain a combobox having the names of birds.
4. In second row, I want to display information about "Animals" i.e. first column will have text as
   "Animals" and second column will contain a combobox having the names of animals.

Please let me know how can I achieve this in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell how your data look like? Do you want fixed 2 rows?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Add column combo box type]

you can add column in data grid viewer and set its type Combo box.